# Interface Builder Outlets. Where can I find them?

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder, outlet

I can create an Outlet from a ViewController to a View by Ctrl Drag between viewcontroller bar button and the view.

It appears in the context view of the ViewController Bar button.

Where does the outlet created like this appear in code? (or doesn't it?).
The problem I am having is that when I make an Outlet from a view to its controller I sometimes (frequently?) find the pop up choice does not include my View. In other words if I made a view called picView I should see picView as a choice along with view but I only see view.

Later, I find my delegate ViewController methods will not run. When I go back to make the link again, I find mysteriously that my view is now an option and that fixes the issue.

Here are two pictures that illustrate the issue.
[image: Picture Without Link]
Here there is no link available

[image: Picture where link has appeared]
Here there is a link available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having gone through the process of creating an App specially to illustrate this point I have discovered that I was looking the wrong way round. Rather than Interface Builder Creating the Outlet I have to put it into the ViewController and then IB can use it to make the link.

This is achieved when I put the outlet into the interface of the ViewController.m file illustrated below. At that moment, the link appears in IB.

```
//
//  SecondViewController.m
//  Empty Test
//
//  Created by Brian Lockwood on 07/09/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "PicView.h"

@interface SecondViewController() <PicViewDataSourceDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet PicView *picView; //<<<<<<<<< this line here
```

@end